# How to mark authentication as failed when no local user in data store

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, openam

I'm setting up SSO with OpenAM for SP and COT.
In Authentication Settings I set "User Profile" to "Required" (meaning that there must be the local user to match and pass the authentication).
My question is: how do I mark the authentication as FAILED when no local user found in data store (I use embedded datastore) so I could redirect user to "Default Failure Login URL"? Currently when no local user found it will redirect to OpenAM login page.
I'm using OpenAM 13.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the AM code I see this is not possible. This has to be processed at the SP layer, so I just set "User Profile" to "Ignored" for remaining work to be processed at SP.